# Can't Open Office Attachments in Outlook After Update

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

After update office can not open attachment file on Rich text Mode , how can I fix it without reinstalling office , because  have this problem user over 100+

[cannot open attachment file on Rich text Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcm0b.png)

[Update List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t1vJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to open normal word document?

In picture, It seems that attachment is word file. First, try to open any word document from your pc to make sure its opening normally and word is default program to open .doc files.

If you are unable to open any word document from your PC and getting error then you might have to set Microsoft word as default program.

If you are able to open word file normally from your PC then try to open any other attachment from your outlook to cross check that problem with outlook attachments, only some of the attachment or any common format(like.. word, pdf).

Let me know the status so that I can guide you further.

Comment: Find the problem     KB3203467